# undefined when query realm db async

Tags: react-native, realm

I am trying to query from realm db but it is undefined.

DogService.js

```
import Realm from 'realm';
import {databaseOptions} from '../models'

    export const DogService  = {
        findAll: async () => {
            Realm.open(databaseOptions).then(
                realm => {
                    const result = realm.objects('Dog')
                    console.log(result) // <=got result
                    return result;
                });
        },
        save: () => {
            Realm.open(databaseOptions).then(
                realm => {
                    realm.write(() => {
                        realm.create('Dog', {name: 'Alex'})
                    });
                });
        }
    }
```

App.js

```
async componentDidMount() {
     let realm = await DogService.findAll();
    console.log(realm); // <= undefined
}
```